# Ubuntu 18.04 If Desktop -> "Show Icons" is Enabled, It Causes Multiple (Unclickable) Icons

Tags: gnome, icons

My desktop icons are duplicated if this option is enabled, but only 1 of the icons are clickable (the other icon is a "shadow" if that makes any sense). Any idea on how to fix this? I need "Show Icons" enabled for the shortcuts to Home, Network, Trash, Mounted Patitions, etc (BTW, these icons are not duplicated, but they are unclickable or movable also...)

[unclickable icons screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSUL.png)

In this picture, rc.link has 2 of the same icons, but the top right one isn't clickable or movable. Also the icons added by Tweaks (Network, Trash, Home, etc) are also unclickable and unmovable. If I create a new folder on the desktop, it will also create a duplicate unclickable icon next to it.
[duplicate folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7GPd.png)

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem. Nemo and Nautilus were fighting for control over drawing the desktop... solution:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false   
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true   
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

Add "nemo-desktop" to start-ups

Then do this if you want the icons:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nemo.desktop home-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nemo.desktop computer-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nemo.desktop trash-icon-visible true
gsettings set org.gnome.nemo.desktop network-icon-visible true
```

**Never touch any options in Tweak -> Desktop again as I'm pretty sure it re-enables Nautilis**

Comment: I get `No such schema “org.nemo.desktop”`
What exactly do you mean by "Add "nemo-desktop" to start-ups"?

Comment: If you are getting the error `No such schema “org.gnome.nemo.desktop”` use the the schema `org.nemo.desktop` (tested on Ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to disable desktop settings in nautilus. 
One way to do this: in dconf-editor go to: 
org.gnome.nautilus.desktop 
and turn "trash-icon-visible" off. 
Or type in terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can purge Desktop Icons extension.

```
sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons
```